# Base global system for two customizable subcomponents

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton, c++14

The following explanation is rather detailed, but I think if I simplified the problem at hand no proper answer could be given.

I'm working on a scripting system for a game (for end users rather than internal developer usage). The game has both singleplayer and multiplayer modes. There is a base `Script` class, inherited by `MultiplayerScript` and `SingleplayerScript` (natually, multiplayer scripts will have certain multiplayer-specific functions/APIs - think player IP addresses etc).

I also have code to load and manage the scripts; the code is largely shared between MP and SP modes (parsing the `load` command issued by the user, for instance), but there are some minor differences - the directory where the code should look for scripts, the way a script is instantiated (depending on the mode, I will want to instantiate `SingleplayerScript` or `MultiplayerScript`). The concept of inheritance springs to mind - perhaps a base `ScriptManager` with all the common code plus a few abstract methods to be overridden by mode-specific subclasses that implement specific functionality. As an example:

```
void ScriptManager::load(const std::string& command)
{
    const auto name = getNameFromCommand(command);
    // This is a virtual method that returns an instantiated script object
    const std::shared_ptr<Script> script = instantiateFromName(name);
    script->initialize();
    scripts.push(script);
}
```

The issue is that the `ScriptManager` concept is inherently global; it will hold, for example, a list of all presently loaded scripts (as pointers to the base `Script` class). Some other common code might want to access this information. However, if I simply subclass `ScriptManager` to implement this specific functionality, I will need to manually instantiate `MultiplayerScriptManager` somewhere in multiplayer code, and likewise for the singleplayer mode. This means shared code no longer has access to the script manager instance.

Now, again, the first thing that springs to mind is the singleton pattern, but I don't believe this mixes well with inheritance; while it's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9372743/1928235), I'm not convinced it's the most elegant solution ever, and given that this isn't such an exotic problem, I feel like there has to be a better way.

The above is simply what I was able to think of (and rejected as unsatisfactory); the question is how to solve this problem in an elegant way, not how to solve it by connecting singletons and inheritance (although if that turns out to be the best way, so be it).

My platform is C++14, although I believe the solutions will probably extend to C# or Java etc as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from the question but I'm assuming you need to mix single and multiplayer scripts.

If so, then I would recommend you have one, global `ScriptManager` but, rather than subclass `instantiateFromName`, make this a factory method.

In this scheme, `instantiateFromName` would decide which script type to instantiate, presumably based on something about the name or the command, and return that object.

`ScriptManager` would only ever work on the abstract supertype and as such wouldn't need subclassing. It could then be a global singleton or however you want to manage global state.

Answer (score 0):

[CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) comes to my mind, but more details would be needed to determine if this is applicable. Also, it would be hard to predict whether you will eventually encounter use cases which CRTP can't solve.

CRTP basically allows you to write the code for the method body, accessing fields that don't exist at the base class at all - instead they would be declared by the respective concrete child classes that inherit from the CRTP class. It is like a parent having access to a child's bank account.

---

A simpler alternative is to have virtual methods that provide access to the underlying fields in each child class.

Note that these virtual methods can't be called while the base class constructor or destructor is executing.

---

To explore these options, you will need to write prototype code that willfully violate "Tell, Don't Ask" rule. Try to prototype the shared functions as if they aren't member functions. Instead, this non-member function will use getters and setters to access and manipulate the child instance's data.

It may be the case that the possibility of sharing code between the two child classes is an illusion (something that seems possible and logical, but reality may tell you that the code will become so different that sharing is not possible). In this case you may have to go back to an abstract base class, which defines interaction points without providing function implementations (method body).

---

Instantiation is the easy part - just instantiate the two concrete instances, at the application level (it can be a static member of the concrete class, or outside).

Instantiate both SP and MP objects even if the game can only be in one mode at a time). Delay initialize some stuff if possible. In a complex application like a game, two-phase / multi-phase initialization can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reasonable use case where you would want to introduce a third mode, besides single- and multi-player? If not, then you don't need extensibility.

From your description it seems like the differences in behavior of the scripting between single- and multi-player mode is minimal. In that case, the best option is to *not* use inheritance, but instead just use an `enum` member variable to keep track of the mode. Where behavior differs between modes, just use if/else to differentiate.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the singleton pattern. This pattern simply puts the single global static field into the class, which is not what you want. You can still use a global static field, just keep it at the application layer, not in the manager classes.